# Why does svn allow to overwrite previous commits?

Tags: svn, commit, radix, revision

If there are two users working on the same file, and `user A` commits before `user B`, `user A`'s commits get overwritten without warning.

Why is this and is there any way to prevent this?

This just happened here and I had to fix it by patching the changes `user A` had made after `user B`'s commit.

This seems to be dangerous, can't svn tell that the base of particular file hadn't been updated?

Comment: Was your file a binary file or an ascii file?

Answer (score 2):

SVN won't just overwrite `userA`s commits unless `userB` explicitly asks it to.  It's not something that can happen by accident.

When `userB` tries to commit their file, SVN will show an error
[image]

Now `userB` will need to do an SVN update.  There are two ways this can go now depending on the type of file:

## ASCII

SVN is really designed to work with ascii (text) files.  If you do an SVN update, it will "merge" the changes from `userA` into `userB`s file.  This means any lines changed by `userA` will be changed in `userB`s working copy. `userB` should really review the merge to ensure that the changes don't break what `userB` was trying to do.  If both users changed the same lines, then a conflict will be flagged.  `userB` will need to review the conflict, figure out what `userA` was trying to accomplish, then manually decide what to do to preserve the changes of both users.

## Binary

SVN isn't really designed to merge binary files.  When merging is applicable, then you need to rely on tools which are really custom-built for that particular binary.  When `userB` performs the update, there will be a conflict and `userB` will be unable to review the differences and merge the files.  If no merge tools are available for that particular binary type, `userB` will need to accept `userA`'s version and then re-make the changes to the binary using whatever tool produces that binary.

`userB` could bypass this workflow by saving a copy of his/her working copy, performing the `svn update`, then restoring the copy and commiting.  This would revert all of `userA`'s changes.  In this ASCII case especially, this is known as a douche move. In the binary case, the two users should really communicate and decide which of the two will need to redo their work.

When working with binary files in SVN, this can become a big problem.  The solution is to commit frequently or to use the [acquire lock](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) feature.  Also, be sure to `svn update` immediately before working on the file, and `svn commit` as soon as you finish your changes.

If `userB` just destroyed a large amount of work by refusing to merge, then you can always rever `userB`'s commit, and ask them to try again.